# jQuery .on / .off event handling, order, and proper removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fThMa/2/**

Clicking inside the note / rend text fields and then double clicking any of the 4 TDs below inserts into the note / rend textfields appropriate HTML entities, even removing highlighted text and inserting at the current cursor position.

What should happen is: Click in note, then double click an entity, then double click an entity again. The result should be one entity inserted into the note text field where the cursor was and further double click events stop.

The problem is, if someone clicks outside the note / rend text fields without dblclicking an entity TD, then that `dblclick` event handler is never removed. Only until they double click an entity and have that entity inserted is the dblclick event handler removed.

Another bug is, every time note / rend is given focus, a new event handler is created and attached, so that if I click note / rend several times and then double click an entity, that entity is inserted for each time I originally clicked on note / rend.

What would be the best way to get this to only fire once and only create a single event handler?

Moving the .off outside the `.on` removes the `.on` as soon as it is set, never letting the function in `.on` to run.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
        $.fn.getText = function() {
            var elem = $(this).get(0);
            var posStart = 0;
            
            if('selectionStart' in elem) {
                if (elem.selectionStart > elem.selectionEnd) {
                    posEnd = elem.selectionStart;
                    posStart = elem.selectionEnd;
                } else {
                    posEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
                    posStart = elem.selectionStart;
                }
                if (posStart != posEnd) {
                    $(elem).val($(elem).val().substring(0, posStart) + $(elem).val().substring(posEnd));
                }
            }
            return posStart;
        }
    })(jQuery);
        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#attributes table tr td").on("blur", "input", function(event) {
            var elem = $(this);
            $("#entities table").one("dblclick", "tr", function(event) {
                var cursorPos = $(elem).getText();
                var entity = $(this).children(":first").children(":first").val();
                var beg = $(elem).val().substring(0, cursorPos);
                var end = $(elem).val().substring(cursorPos);
                $(elem).val(beg + entity + end);
                $("#entities table").off("dblclick", "tr");
            });
        });
    });​

<div id="attributes">
  <table>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td><p>note</p></td>
        <td><input id="note" name="note" type="text" value="note"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td><p>rend</p></td>
        <td><input id="rent" name="rend" type="text" value="rend"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="entities">
  <table>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="ent1-val" hidden="true" type="text" value="&amp;lt;"></td>
        <td><input id="ent1-vis" type="text" value="<"></td>
        <td><input id="ent1-name" type="text" value="Less Than"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
    <form>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="ent2-val" hidden="true" type="text" value="&amp;gt;"></td>
        <td><input id="ent2-vis" type="text" value=">"></td>
        <td><input id="ent2-name" type="text" value="Greater Than"></td>
      <tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>​
```

Comment: I'm probably not alone in this, I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please clarify what you want to happen and what is happening instead? It appears to be working for me in google chrome. I click the text field, double click one of the td's below, and the td's value ends up in the original text field. additional doubleclicks do nothing. Also, the `.off` is redundant in the code you posted above since you used `.one`

Comment: In re-reading my post, I see that I have indeed been quite clear in what I want to happen as opposed to what is happening. The .one was a test...and that redundancy aside, the problems noted in the 3rd and 4th paragraphs still exist.

Comment: I see a problem with your html (possibly unrelated, but a problem nonetheless). table nodes can only have tbody tfoot thead and tr nodes as children. direct form nodes is invalid. This obviously drastically affects how your code would need to be formatted. With the form nodes where they are currently, they will not work consistently across all browsers.

Comment: The only real way to fix the problem in paragraph three is to either remove the event on a setTimeout if the event doesn't happen in x amount of time, or remove it any time y event happens. There really isn't enough context to help you decide which one is best. What tells the user that they need to click the input then the table?

Comment: Basically, you haven't really demonstrated a problem. You've demonstrated unfinished logic. "I have an event that gets bound when you click x, but if you click y it doesn't get unbound". the obvious answer is unbind it when you click y. But you may also want to unbind it when you click z or after n amount of time depending on the GUI.

Comment: Kevin, your comments were correct. I knew this was an incomplete logic question. I revised the way I was doing the event handling and updated the jsFiddle. If you write out an answer, I'll accept it. http://jsfiddle.net/fThMa/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest unbinding the event when the event that binds it gets triggered, preventing the doubleclick event from being bound twice. You may also want to unbind it after n seconds, or possibly after clicking elsewhere on the page.

```
$("#entities table").off("dblclick","tr")
                    .on("dblclick", "tr",
                           function() {
                               //do stuff 
                           });
```